# Easing out transition in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm just starting with React and running into an issue with something I was expecting to be quite simple. All I'm trying to do is have a block of text fade in and then fade out based on a simple trigger, but I can't get it to fade out.

The code is below and I've got a button that makes the message appear. It is fading in fine and disappearing after two seconds, but I was expecting the message to fade out upon leaving... but clearly I'm misunderstanding the meaning of that in the React-ish transition CSS.

Here is the React component:

```
class MessageSender extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let sent_element = null;
    if (this.state.linkSent) {
      sent_element = <AnimatedText/>;
    }
  return (
    <div>
      {sent_element}
    </div>
  );


    //A fetch then triggers:
    ...then((json) => {
      if (json.success) {
        _this.setState({
          linkSent: true
        })
        setTimeout(
            function(){
              _this.setState({linkSent:false});
            },2000
        )
      }
    });
}

class AnimatedText extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ReactTransitionGroup transitionAppear={true} transitionName="fadeInOut">
      <div>Sent!</div>
    </ReactTransitionGroup>;
  }
}
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.fadeInOut-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.fadeInOut-appear.fadeInOut-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fadeInOut-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.fadeInOut-leave.fadeInOut-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`, the high level API around `ReactTransitionGroup`

```
import `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` from "react-addons-css-transition-group";
```

In React `> v0.14`, you must also pass `transitionEnterTimeout` `transitionLeaveTimeout`and optionally `transitionAppearTimeout` props to the component if you have `transitionAppear` enabled (which you do).

Lastly, you need to pass `key`-attribute to your animated children

> You must provide the key attribute for all children of ReactCSSTransitionGroup, even when only rendering a single item. This is how React will determine which children have entered, left, or stayed.

You might also have to refactor your code a bit so that your `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` is not inside the `<AnimatedText >`, but instead is wrapped around your `{sent_element}`

See [React/Animation-docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) for more information.

Comment: I am using the imports: `import addons from 'react/addons';
var ReactTransitionGroup = addons.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;` and am getting the appear transition to fade in perfectly over 400ms. What exactly triggers the **leave** condition? I tried incrementally beefing up my transition group, but couldn't get anything along the way to work. It ended up looking like this :`<ReactTransitionGroup key="sentstuff" transitionAppear={true} transitionName="fadeInOut" transitionEnterTimeout={400} transitionAppearTimeout={400} transitionLeaveTimeout={400}>`. Same behavior if around sent_element, too.

Comment: Did you add the `key`-attribute to the children? As in `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup /**/><div **key={this.props.somethingUnique}**>foo</div></ReactCSSTransitionGroup>` ? The key-value (that must be unique to the element) is needed for React to figure out if your component has left. Check the DevTools on your browser when you are triggering your element.

Answer (score 0):

For more animation fun see the react-motion lib available on GitHub https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion